# Unresolved reference: Curry

Tags: kotlin

I want to print out labels of spices in SpiceContainer but I get
[image]
Here is my code. How do I solve this?

```
package Spice
fun main(args: Array<String> ) {
    jack()
}

class Spice(){
    val name:String=("Curry")
    val spiciness:String=("mild")
}
data class SpiceContainer(var spice: Spice){
    val label=spice.name
}

fun jack(){
    val spiceCabinet = listOf(SpiceContainer(Curry("Yellow Curry", "mild")),
            SpiceContainer(Curry("Red Curry", "medium")),
            SpiceContainer(Curry("Green Curry", "spicy")))
    for(element in spiceCabinet) println(element.label)
}
```

Comment: There is no `class Curry` in your code (at least in the code you posted). You have a `class Spice` with fix value `name = "Curry"` and I doubt that's what you want. Could you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to print out label of containers. https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9011/lessons/77b7bbc2-3cf4-4e01-b03e-455b36cb9ced/concepts/268a9251-7052-489e-8dd8-d78c53ee26df  I am learning kotlin from udacity but I guess their answer codes are neither correct nor clear nor completed. I rewrite to class Spice(val name: String, val spiciness: String){} and change SpiceContainer(Curry to SpiceContainer(Spice then it works fine.

Comment: That link requires an account... I already have far too many,. so I refuse to create another one.

Comment: You can use google acct to login just like I use google acct to login this site without create a new acct. Its fine if you don't want to. You have help a lot already.

Comment: It's better here to post the actual question as text or at least the most importantn parts of it along with one's own effort. That way, nobody would have to have a google account or any other identity.
Glad to have helped... Thanks for accepting the answer. Please consider an upvote if you have enough reputation for that.

Comment: Posting that link is trying to let you see where the question comes from and I only ask a question when I put efforts for hours and can Not solve it. This is a simple question to you but I spent hours for that and still can't solve it. Thank you again. I feel connected and I have click an upvote to your answer which I didn't know I could do that:-)

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, too. Don't get me wrong, your question is just missing the actual goal of your code, you definitely have posted your effort, that's basically why I answered ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of a `class Curry` you just don't have. Instead, you have a `class Spice` with a `name` and a `spiciness`. If you want an instance of, say *Red Curry*, you would have to instantiate a `Spice` and give it the desired `name`: `Spice("Red Curry", "kinda hot")`.
A good practice for that `spiciness` (at least a better one than just a `String`) would be an `enum class Spiciness`...

Here's a simple example:

```kotlin
// a spice consisting of a name and some degree of spiciness
data class Spice(val name: String, val spiciness: Spiciness)

// the spice container that gets the label of the spice contained
data class SpiceContainer(val spice: Spice) {
    val label: String = spice.name
}

// enumerate possible degrees of spiciness
enum class Spiciness {
    NONE_AT_ALL,
    MILD,
    MODERATE,
    HOT,
    DANGEROUSLY_HOT,
    LIFE_THREATENING,
    UNKNOWN_TRY_YOURSELF
}

fun jack() {
    // create a list of spices and add some arbitrary ones
    val spiceCabinet = listOf(SpiceContainer(Spice("Yellow Curry", Spiciness.MODERATE)),
                              SpiceContainer(Spice("Red Curry", Spiciness.HOT)),
                              SpiceContainer(Spice("Green Curry", Spiciness.UNKNOWN)),
                              SpiceContainer(Spice("Pepper", Spiciness.MILD)))
     // print each item's label
     spiceCabinet.forEach{ it -> println(it.label) }
                              
}
```

and run the `fun jack()` like this

```kotlin
fun main() {
    jack()
}
```

in order to get an output of

```
Yellow Curry
Red Curry
Green Curry
Pepper
```

I don't really get why you need or want the `SpiceContainer`, but that's beyond the scope of this answer (and question, most likely).

Comment: Your solution is perfect !!! If I remove SpiceContainer => val spiceCabinet = listOf(Spice("Yellow Curry", "mild") then label of println(element.label) becomes red. Alert: Unsolved Reference: label, how to solve this?

Comment: @LisaBaron That line gets an error because you then have a list of `Spice`s instead of a list of `SpiceContainer`s. You need to change it to `element.name` because a `Spice`'s `name` is actually what a `SpiceContainer`'s `label` was getting its value from.

Comment: I appreciate your time in answering my question. Since you have spent time, you must think my question have some value. Would you please up vote this question? This question will benefit others in the future as well.